# Updating MS SQL objects with dependencies

Tags: sql-server

I have sql scripts `DROP ... CREATE...` for views, procedures, triggers, functions (in files on disk). I need to run this scripts to update database structure.

But order of executing scripts is important. Because if view1 depends on view2, and I run scripts for view1 first, an error may occurs.

Let's suppose that there are no adscititious dependencies in my scripts, so database knows about all dependencies.

Is there a way to select all this objects names from sql server in dependency order? So I can run scripts in this order and not afraid about above errors.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this sql:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
declare @deps TABLE (name nvarchar(512), dep_name nvarchar(512))
declare @ordered TABLE (name nvarchar(512), [level] INT)

insert @deps(name, dep_name)
SELECT DISTINCT CAST(OBJ.name as nvarchar(512)) AS ObjectName, 
                CAST(REFOBJ.name as nvarchar(512)) AS ReferencedObjectName
FROM sys.sql_dependencies AS DEP
     INNER JOIN
     sys.objects AS OBJ
         ON DEP.object_id = OBJ.object_id
     INNER JOIN
     sys.schemas AS SCH
         ON OBJ.schema_id = SCH.schema_id
     INNER JOIN sys.objects AS REFOBJ
         ON DEP.referenced_major_id = REFOBJ.object_id
     INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS REFSCH
         ON REFOBJ.schema_id = REFSCH.schema_id
     LEFT JOIN sys.columns AS REFCOL
         ON DEP.class IN (0, 1)
            AND DEP.referenced_minor_id = REFCOL.column_id
            AND DEP.referenced_major_id = REFCOL.object_id
WHERE OBJ.type_desc IN ('VIEW','SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE','SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION','SQL_TRIGGER','SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION')
    AND REFOBJ.type_desc IN ('VIEW','SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE','SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION','SQL_TRIGGER','SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION')

insert @ordered(name, [level])
select distinct d1.dep_name, 1 as [level]
from @deps d1
    LEFT JOIN @deps d2 ON d1.dep_name = d2.name
where d2.name IS NULL

WHILE EXISTS(select * from @deps)
BEGIN 
    delete d
    FROM @deps d
        JOIN @ordered o ON d.name = o.name

    insert @ordered(name, [level])
    SELECT DISTINCT d0.name, (select MAX([level]) + 1 FROM @ordered) 
    FROM @deps d0
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT d.name
            from @deps d
                LEFT JOIN @ordered o ON d.dep_name = o.name
            WHERE o.name IS NULL
        ) dfilter ON d0.name = dfilter.name
    WHERE dfilter.name is NULL
END

select * from @ordered
ORDER by level asc
```